# C system call read from stdin and write to a file

Tags: c, shell, system-calls

I am writing a C program for this: `cat file.txt | wc > wc.txt`
this is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    int fd, piped[2], pid, p2p0[2];
    pipe(piped);

    pid = fork();

    if (pid == 0)
    {
        close(1);
        dup(piped[1]);
        close(piped[1]);
        close(piped[0]);
        execl("/bin/cat", "cat", "file.txt", (char *)0);
    }

    pipe(p2p0);
    pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0)
    {
        close(0);
        dup(piped[0]);
        close(piped[1]);
        close(piped[0]);

        close(1);
        dup(p2p0[1]);
        close(p2p0[1]);
        close(p2p0[0]);
        execl("/bin/wc", "wc", (char *)0);
    }

    close(piped[1]);
    close(piped[0]);
    close(p2p0[1]);

    close(0);
    dup(p2p0[0]);
    close(p2p0[0]);

    fd = open("wc.txt", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, 0777);
    close(1);
    dup(fd);
    close(fd);


    return 0;
}
```

the wc.txt file is created, but my program don't print inside wc.txt.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

The pipeline you are creating is essentially

```
cat file.txt | wc | true >wc.txt
```

that is, the output of wc is being piped to another process (your parent C program after the forks) that does nothing other than exiting with success.

What you need to do is *not* create the second pipe, and instead dup the fd from the `open("wc.txt",` ... to be wc's stdout.

Note that you also don't need the second fork -- since you don't need/want to do anything after wc, you can just do the `execl("wc"` ... call in the parent process and don't need a second child.